# How to call the .php in WordPress URL properly?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-rewriting

I have 2 php files. One for getting the inputted email of the user (subscriptions), encrypt that email and send an email with confirmation link to the user. The second one, is for decryption of the email.

This 2 php files are working, but when I click the confirmation link, I encounter an error, like this "Oops! That page can’t be found."

Here's the live URL http://bit.ly/1n718S1

I tried this solution https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39765/how-to-add-a-php-file-to-wordpress, but it's not working

Note: I use these 2 PHP files for a specific page only

Here's the link http://bit.ly/1NDAnQA

Here's some of the PHP script of the 1st PHP file

```
$subscriptions = $_POST['subscriptions'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(!($_POST['subscriptions']=="")){
    $subscriptions= $_POST['subscriptions'];

    function encryptLink($string){
        $key = "123456789";
        $qryStr = "email=".$string1;
        $query = base64_encode(urlencode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $qryStr, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key)))));
        $link = "_confirmation.php?".$subscriptions.''.$query;
        $baseURL = "http://homecredit.ph/testEnvironment/";

        return $link;
    }
        $pagelink = encryptLink($string);
        $string = $subscriptions;

        //Email Details
        $mail_to = $subscriptions;
        $from_mail = "";
        $from_name = "";
        $reply_to = "";
        $subject = "Email Verification";
        $message_body = 'Hey, http://homecredit.ph/testEnvironment/'.$pagelink.'';
```

Answer (score 0):

when you call the .php make sure to include the full path to it:

e.g.

```
http://homecredit.ph/testEnvironment/yourfile.php
http://homecredit.ph/testEnvironment/yourfile2.php
```

(If this doesn't work, try to enable 'fopen' php function in your server)